# Oracle MINUS both ways (get difference between select)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find all the rows in two `select` statements, where the row belongs (all columns matches) to *either* select statement but *not both*.

I know how to achieve this in in a single direction

```
  select foo from foobar where bar = 1
minus
  select foo from foobar where bar = 2;
```

This would return all the rows where foo is present in the first select statement but not the last, but not other way around.

I know I could do

```
    (select foo from foobar where bar = 1
  minus
    select foo from foobar where bar = 2)
union
    (select foo from foobar where bar = 2
  minus
    select foo from foobar where bar = 1);
```

Which returns the desired result. But this is a lot of repetition. Is there some operator like `minus` which works the both ways?

Also, I would like to add identifier to the result, which indicates to which select it belongs. But this alone will make all rows different.

Comment: Correct me if I be mistaken, but wouldn't records for which `bar = 1` implicitly be distinct from records for which `bar = 2` (or any other value)?  Maybe you should update with a better example.

Comment: I'm not returning all columns, but just a specific column(s), which may be common or different regardless of the bar

Comment: It might be helpful to others if you show us some actual sample data here.  A picture is worth a thousands words definitely applies to SQL query questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Set operations (UNION, INTERSECT, MINUS) remove duplicates. Only UNION ALL preserves all duplicates. So - first question - are the two rowsets for which you want to compute the symmetric difference de-duplicated already? ("Symmetric difference" is the technical term for the set operation you are asking about; the set-theoretic equivalent of "exclusive OR".) If they are de-duplicated already, then yes, there are more efficient ways, but first please clarify this.

Comment: Isn't this just a full outer join on the matching fields (columns in select) where they are null in one or the other table?

Comment: @xQbert - the result may be the same, but a full outer join does more work. To compute a join, for a row from the first "table", all rows in the second "table" are inspected to see if they match - even after the first match was found. For the MINUS operation, that is not necessary. In addition, MINUS de-duplicates the inputs; the outer join does not.

Answer (score 2):

The SET operators are only

> UNION    All distinct rows selected by either query
>
> UNION ALL   All rows selected by either query, including all
>   duplicates
>
> INTERSECT All distinct rows selected by both queries
>
> MINUS All distinct rows selected by the first query but not the second

you could use intersect but the number of select are pratically the same

```
  (select foo from foobar where bar = 1
  union 
  select foo from foobar where bar = 2)
  minus 
  (select foo from foobar where bar = 1
  intesect
  select foo from foobar where bar = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two rowsets (be they base tables or the results of other computations) are already de-duplicated, then you can use

```
select foo
from (
       select foo from rowset_1
       union all
       select foo from rowset_2
     )
group by foo
having count(*) = 1
```

The advantage - especially if the rowsets are base tables - is that each is only scanned once, instead of twice each.

If the result sets are not de-duplicated already, you may change `select foo` with `select distinct foo` in both places.

There is a similar solution if you may have duplicates in each result set, and you also want to show rows (`foo` values) that are common to both tables, but with different multiplicities (say, three duplicates in one rowset but five duplicates in the other).

Answer (score 0):

In this case (always the same table) you can simply aggregate:

```
select foo, max(bar)
from foobar 
where bar in (1,2)
group by foo
having count(distinct bar) = 1;
```

This gives you all foo that have only either bar 1 or bar 2 and not both. And `max(bar)` tells you which of the two values a foo has.